# Can you see if IP restrictions are configured for Logic Apps via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way to see the IP restrictions on a Logic App? I would like the ability to verify that the apps running have appropriate IP restrictions. I know there's no command to configure the IP restrictions from powershell but is there anyway some how to see them via powershell? I'm able to view the via resource explorer but I wasn't sure if there's any way to see them via powershell.

Comment: The Azure Resource Explorer has a PowerShell tab, is that not populated for you when you view the part that shows IP restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

The `Ip restrictions` is part of the `Access Control`. you can just query the azure resource directly:

```
# Don't forget to login with Login-AzureRMAccount

# Get the resource
$myLogicApp = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -ResourceName my-logic-app-name -ApiVersion 2016-06-01

# Get the ip restrictions:
$myLogicApp.Properties.accessControl.allowedCallerIpAddresses
```

Answer (score 0):

$LogicAppConfig.Properties.accessControl.triggers.allowedCallerIpAddresses

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer, but can you also add an explanation of how your code solves the problem?